With CSS How Can I Make Vertical Border Stretch to 100% Height of Two Columns
I'm using Foundation's row / column layout.
// Layout

<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns navs">...</div>  <!-- nav links -->
  <div class="medium-9 columns content">...</div> <!-- page content -->
</div>


<style>
.navs {
  border-right: solid 1px #000; //black
}
.content {
  border-left: solid 1px #000; //black
}
</style>

I want to have a vertical border that stretches the length/height of the shared border/side of these two columns. My problem is that while both columns appear to be the same height (container-wise), their content is rarely uniform in length.  On some pages the nav links appear longer than the content in the content div.  On some, the content in the content div is longer.
Regardless of which class I style a border on, there are pages that show a gap at the bottom of the border because it only extends to length of the content in that div.
Added note: the layout for the two-columns is in an includes file. It is not added manually to each page. Each page calls the layout.
Any thoughts on how to fix this?
Thanks,

Just use display: flex on the container and by default the containers will both be the same height. E.g.


.row {display: flex;}
.row div {min-height: 100px; min-width: 100px; background: #e7e7e7;} /* for demo purposes */
.navs {
  border-right: solid 1px #000; 
}
.content {
  border-left: solid 1px #000; 
}
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns navs">...</div>  <!-- nav links -->
  <div class="medium-9 columns content">...</div> <!-- page content -->
</div>




#ralph.m  Thanks for your reply.  That worked!!!  I tried flex before, but it made my columns equal width.  The flex I tried had css: flex: 1 in each column style.  Maybe that was my issue with it.  Thank you again
